# trying to make ASCII graph python 3

Tags: python, loops, printing, graph, ascii

I'm trying to make an ASCII graph using python loops.
The goal is for the user to enter an input (formula) [x+1] etc. and print out the graph.
The domain and range of the graph only goes from -10 to +10.

I managed to get it working, but only for the formula (-x+1), which is (x+1) in my code.

I know the problem is because my loop starts printing it from the top, so I would have to change it so it prints the loop in the negative direction, but I am stuck on how to combine my graph into a nested loop so it prints it out properly, and then replaces the corresponding place of the function output.

I'm thinking now that maybe I should make it print out the '*' line then the graph around it, but I think that's more complicated.

I can give you any more information if you need.

Any constructive thoughts would be much appreciated.

Here is my code, let me know what you think.

```
height=20
w=10
x=0
for a in range(0,11):
    ps= ((" " * w)+('|')+(" " * w))
    ps=list(ps)
    ps[x]="*"
    x=x+1
    pp="".join(ps)
    print(pp)



rs=(('-'*10)+('+')+('-'*10))
rs=list(rs)
rs[x]="*"
rr="".join(rs)
print(rr)

for a in range(0,10):
    ws = ((" " * w)+('|')+(" " * w))
    ws=list(ws)
    y=x+1
    ws[y]="*"
    x=x+1
    wp="".join(ws)
    print(wp)
```

This is the output below:

```
*         |          
 *        |          
  *       |          
   *      |          
    *     |          
     *    |          
      *   |          
       *  |          
        * |          
         *|          
          *          
----------+*---------
          | *        
          |  *       
          |   *      
          |    *     
          |     *    
          |      *   
          |       *  
          |        * 
          |         *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate method of solving the problem:

1. Create a 2d array, each element being a character
2. Pre-fill out the background graph lines
3. Loop through each x position, and calculate the rounded y position
4. Insert the positions as `*` into your 2d array
5. Finally print out the whole 2d array as a set of lines

For 5, here's a handy snippet of python code - `''.join(myArray)`

You'll notice that this solution method separates the calculation of what the data result should be, from the actual output. This is often a good way to separate your logic in a simple program:

1. Process, filter, sanatize and organise your programs input data
2. Do data processing on the input
3. Formulate, format and output the processed data

If you organise your programs by these three general / 'meta' steps, it can help to organise your code a lot more and make it more understandable.

Comment: I would add that if the final goal is to graph any function he would have to first calculate the min and max y values as the dimension of the array depends on those. Also, I'm not sure that ''.join(myArray) would work for a 2D array.

Comment: @civilu you'd do that for each row of the 2D array, not on the array itself.

Comment: Could you please expand on this a little bit?

Do I need to make an array with 20 lines? or just the 4 characters that are in use?

How would I loop through each x position to calculate the y? would that be with a nested loop?

Comment: @gunter yes, with a 2D array you would use a two-level nested loop to iterate over all its elements.

You would consider the array to represent a plane of integer values. Initially you would fill it with spaces, and if you like you could fill in the axis markers, and then you'd iterate over it to fill in the line markers.

If the array is size 20x20, you'd loop over a range say (-10, 10) to iterate over each x value and calculate the corresponding y value that needs to be marked.

Comment: @ivo,

Im a beginner in python, so Im fairly new to all this, we havent really covered arrays, so I think I would need more help with this. I dont want to keep pestering you for help, so If I paypal you $5 could you write this up for me and explain it more in depth so I get a better idea?

Thanks